# Uniqueness and the indefinite integral of 1/(1-x)

Tags: calculus

Consider

$$I = \int \frac{1}{1-x}\ dx = -\ln(1-x) + C$$

Now factor out the negative from the integral above and you get

$$I = -\int \frac{1}{x-1}\ dx = -\ln(x-1) + C$$

But aren't the curves given by the two results above... different?

It seems that a *definite* integral of either integral evaluates similarly, but here the indefinite integral appears to not have a unique answer. What's going on here? How can I best understand this?

Comment: $\int \frac {dx} x = \ln |x|+C$.

Comment: @A.S. Oh dear me. It is. Thank you. Should, I uh, close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the value of each integral, respectively, is

$$-\ln|1-x|+C $$ and $$-\ln|x-1| + C$$

So, really, they are the same.